# Going against the conventional $\alpha$?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value

I have a general statistics question on $\alpha$.

Conventionally, $\alpha$ is set at $p < 0.05$. Are there cases where by alpha is set at $p < 0.3$ instead? If so, why?

Also, I understand that by changing the $\alpha$ value, it gives rise to a larger risk of encountering Type $1$ errors (false positive). Thus, how should I interpret the results for such a scenario?

Comment: A smaller $\alpha$ means that one is seeking stronger support for the hypothesis. If one could quantify the cost of a Type I error (or Type II), this would be made into a rational choice. 0.05 Would I guess in absence of cost considerations be categorised subjectively as 'fairly strong'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are reasons to adjust alpha.  The simplest way to explain these is to note what Type I and Type II errors are, and that sometimes a Type II error is much worse than a Type I.  (And to realize that by increasing the chance of one, you decrease the chance of the other).

Suppose, for example, that you develop a drug that treats a previously incurable and terminal disease. Now a Type I error would mean saying the drug works when it doesn't and a Type II error would be saying it doesn't work when it does. In the first case, we give a useless drug to people who are dying; in the second, we fail to treat people who are dying.  I'd say the second is much worse.

Of course, sometimes it's the other way around.

The blind acceptance of 0.05 and 0.20 for type I and type II errors is one of the hardest things to get PHBs to give up.  (PHB = Pointy Haired Boss from Dilbert and could be a journal editor, a boss, a PhD committee or whatever).

Comment: Hey Peter, thank you so much for helping me! I agree that the blind acceptance portion is a big issue in academia. On another note, am I right to say that by adjusting the power, I can reduce the probability of type 1 error, but this will cause my type 2 error to increase? For that matter, do I use an estimation rather than a hypothesis testing framework? i.e. Either using frequentist confidence intervals and effect sizes or using Bayesian statistics with slightly informative priors (because you have only a small sample).

Comment: Yes, lower power = more type II errors, fewer type I errors. Whether to use estimation or confidence intervals depends on what you are trying to find out.